# Custom EventListener on 2sxc formulas

Tags: javascript, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have entity data type with three fields: one dropdown (A), one empty header (B) and one text (C).

[image]

Based on the dropdown value, I run a formula to a custom API and place some html into the header notes so they become visible at the form. This HTML contains a list of input checkboxes and labels.

Now I need to compile these checkboxes (checked and labels) into the field C.

This would be very simple with a plain js running on the form, but with 2sxc I have no clue on how to achieve this.

Here's what I've drafted:

```
v1(data, context) {
  var dataToReturn = "nothing yet";
  
  var getCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.stepInput');
  var getlabels = document.querySelectorAll('.stepLabel');
  
  for (let i = 0; i < getCheckboxes.length; i++) {
    getCheckboxes[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      compileData();
    });
  }

  function compileData() {
    for (let i=0; i<getCheckboxes.length; i++) {
      dataToReturn += getlabels[i].textContent;
    }
  }
  
  return dataToReturn;
}
```

This obviously does not work for several reasons.
I would need the addEventListener in all new checkboxes if the field A is changed and new checkboxes are placed.
I would need to run the formula every time the checkboxes change.

Any tips on how to achieve this?

This obviously would not be needed if 2sxc just allowed a checkbox field type. :)

Answer (score 0):

This should be done using a custom input field.

Basically you can create your own input fields (which in this case would hold a lot of checkboxes, and do something with the result).

There are some tutorials on this here https://2sxc.org/dnn-tutorials/en/razor/ui201/page

Note: if you think that adding a alternate display for boolean to be checkbox is important, open an issue and explain what the benefit would be.

Comment: Thanks. But those tutorials are not nearly enough to achieve what I need. Can you create a demo of a custom field with two checkboxes that stores values?

Comment: Sorry, I know I can't find time for that in the next few weeks. It's basically standard WebComponents and some APIs to talk to the form. So you would create a string-magic-checkboxes control which recieves a string (to set the checkboxes) and returns a string whener the check-states change.